# Why wont my data render onto my card component when using spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I am trying to render data from a data file onto my card component by destructuring an object and using the spread operator (apologies if my jargon is wrong I don't know the exact words to describe it). I have done this in a project previously and tried to copy how I did it but the data will not render - get no issues in the console either.

I have made a code sandbox for it [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/5d75c8f72b3) - you will want to open it in a new window to see the card component in action as I have not made a responsive layout yet so it wont render on smaller screens.

The important files relevant to this are:

- PortfolioCardData.js (stores the data which is exported)
- PortfolioPageHero.js (where the AnimatedCard is rendered and I spread the data as an object into the card)
- AnimatedCard.js & AnimatedCardDetails.js - where I destructure an object in the functions parenthesis and then use objects to place where the title, image etc will go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the file `PortfolioPageHero.js` where you are passing data by destructuring to

```
<AnimatedCard {...PortfolioCardData1}/>
```

where `PortfolioCardDetails1` is an array of objects

```
export const PortfolioCardData1 = [
    {
        key: 2,
        image: "",
        title: "Recipe App",
        subtitle: "Built with React | Mobile First",
        buttonText: "Take a look"
    }
]
```

so when you use spread operator on array to pass the data then that array is passed as a key-value pair of `index : valueAtIndex` somthing like this

```
 "0": {
    key: 1,
    image: "",
    title: "Ecommerce",
    subtitle: "Built with react | Redux | Stripe",
    buttonText: "Take a look"
  }
```

so, you can access this data by doing `props.0.image` , etc or you can spread the object while destructuring like this

```
<AnimatedCard {...PortfolioCardData1[0]}/>
```

then your current code would work.

Comment: Thank You! did not even realise the mistake there, has helped me understand how to structure my data better in the future.